# CakePHP: Adding default faculty/department values while adding a new University

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

New programmer with with CakePHP, I have 3 controllers: Universities, Faculties, Departments.

My tables are: 
universities (id, name, country_id),
faculties(id, name, university_id),
departments (id, name, faculty_id).

When I add a new University, I need to create automatically a default value ('n/a') as a Faculty for this University, and for this created Faculty a default value ('n/a') as Department.
in our system, we need the university having at least one faculty and one faculty.department. So if the new university id = 10, then after saving, I need to create a new faculty (let's say faculties.id = 25) with university_i=10. and a new department with faculty_id = 25.

This is my code UniversitiesController add function

```
$university = $this->Universities->newEntity();

if ($this->request->is('post')) {
   $university = $this->Universities->patchEntity($university, $this->request->data);
   if ($this->Universities->save($university)) {
       $this->Flash->success(__('The university has been saved.'));
       return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
   } else {
       $this->Flash->error(__('The university could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
   }
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you read the incredibly-detailed CakePHP book online?  What specific issue(s) are you having?  What version of CakePHP are you using? ..etc etc etc.

Comment: I think your question is about setting a default value? A real easy way would be to set a default value for the field at the database level. Then if you don't set that field in `$this->request->data` it will save as the default database value. `ALTER TABLE `my_table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `my_column` `my_column` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n/a' ;`

Comment: Also if you setup your associations you can do ->newEntity($data, ['associated' => ['Faculty', 'Department'])  or ->patchEntity($entity, $data, ['associated' => ['Faculty', 'Department'])

Comment: Derek: your suggestion seems to be the good one, and associations are set. But where should I set the faculty to the default value ('n/a'), and then the department to 'n/a'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. in UniversitiesCotroller,

```
public function add()
{
    $university = $this->Universities->newEntity();
    $faculty->_joinData = $this->Universities->Faculties->newEntity();
    $faculty->_joinData->name = 'N/A';
    $university->dirty('faculties', true);


    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $university = $this->Universities->patchEntity($university, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Universities->save($university, ['associated' => ['Faculties']])) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The university has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The university could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $countries = $this->Universities->Countries->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('university', 'countries'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['university']);
}
```

in Universities add.ctp:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($university) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add University') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('name');
            echo $this->Form->input('short_name');
            echo $this->Form->input('country_id', ['options' => $countries]);
            echo $this->Form->input('town');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

In such way, when we add a new university, it creates by defalut a new entry under its faculties ('N/A').

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly is that in the list of universities or faculties you want to have a default value (first value of your list) as (n/a)'s. If that is the case, I had the same issue, the answer was very simple. In the table where you have the list of universities as a first value add the n/a as a value, I recommend to leave it like it is so the first value on your table or SQL result will be displayed as the default value.

next in the option list on your file.ctp you just add values like this...

```
echo $this->Form->control('universities', [
                'options' => $universities,
                'title' => 'Select the university',
                'alt' => 'Select the university',
                'label' => 'Select the university',
                'class'=> 'classForOption',
                'empty' => false
            ]);
```

Being the **'empty' => false** the answer of your question. I hope !

Regards

Comment: Thanks Red. Actually my request is different.
I have 3 tables: universities (id, name, country_id), faculties(id, name, university_id), departments (id, name, faculty_id). When I create a new universitiy, I need to create automatically a 'n/a' faculty for it, and for this faculty I need to create a 'n/a' department, since in our system, we need the university having at least one faculty and one faculty.department.

Comment: i see, in that case is very simple, add the n/a in your faculties table and your departments table and make that as the first element on your table, when it comes to create a new university use the code I posted and will add an 'n/a' value every time you create a university. See, when you create an university in your view the Form->control will automatically will create an 'n/a' value if there is no value selected by the user. Moreover the controller will pass this and write it in to the database even if you are validating on your model. You have to make sure you are implementing relational DB